# Dynamically access member variable of a structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, function-pointers

I have different structures and I want to write a general framework to get a sorted list of elements from say a hashtable or list of these structures in C. For example, if I have a structure definition as

```
struct XYZ{ 
 int a;
 char b[20];
 long time;
}
```

Suppose I have a list of elements of this structure type. I need to have a functionality, by which I can sort this list by any field of the structure and the field would be as given by user. This kind of use case has to be available for other such structures also and hence this sorting framework should be generic. I was thinking of storing different metadata related to this structure in form of a different auto generated structure using some script. This metadata would store information related to each element in the given structure. This information would include type of the structure(viz integer, string or date: types distinct while performing sorting operations) and a way to access this element in the structure. Now my question is what should ideally be the way to access these elements. One straight forward way is to generate some getter functions for each of these and set function pointers of the getter functions in the autogenerated metadata structures. But having a getter function to access each member element would mean a function call for each element access. Would this deter performance of the application ? Can there be any other way to do this? Any other framework ideas to implement the required use case also welcome.

Comment: In general it's not possible. The normal way to solve it is to have one sort function (using the standard [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function is recommended) and a set of comparator functions, one function for each member in the structure.

Comment: So that would mean I have comparison functions for each element of each of the structures?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: `char *b[20]` is 20 char _pointers_, not a string of max 20 chars. If that is what you intended, then you'll have to write a separate `qsort` callback for each member of the struct, if not, you could use `offsetof` + global variable + generic callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggested, the most straightforward approach would be to use `qsort` and a callback for each member of the struct.
You *could* use the `offsetof` macro to create a more generic, single callback.

The dangers of a single callback is that you have to change the function whenever the struct changes. It would also require you to create a global variable, which isn't ideal either. Of course, if you use separate callbacks, you have to create a new function, too. However, you don't have a global, and forgetting to create a new function is something that is far easier to debug and fix.

But just as an example, here's a possible approach for a generic `qsort` callback:

```
#include <stddef.h>

static size_t member_offset;

int struct_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    switch(member_offset)
    {
         case 0://or case offsetof(struct XYZ, a):
             return ((struct XYZ *)a)->a - ((struct XYZ *) b)->a;
         case offsetof(struct XYZ, b):
             return strcmp(
                 ((struct XYZ *)a)->b,
                 ((struct XYZ *)b)->b
             );
         case offsetof(struct XYZ, c):
             return ((struct XYZ *)a)->c - ((struct XYZ *) b)->c;
         default:
             fprintf(stderr, "Invalid offset value %d\n", member_offset);
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );//possible bug
    }
}

int main ( void )
{
    struct XYZ foo[10];//create array of structs
    size_t offsets[3] = { 0, offsetof(struct XYZ, b), offsetof(struct XYZ, c)};
    for (int i=0;i<3;++i)
    {
        member_offset = offsets[i];//omit this, and you're in trouble!
        qsort(
            foo,
            sizeof foo,
            sizeof *foo,
            struct_cmp
        );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can already see, if the struct has, say 10 member fields, the callback is going to look like an unholy mess. Owing to using a global variable, it's also bound to be more vulnerable. Not initializing the global variable, or changing the state of the global variable while another thread is sorting... 
Honestly: just add a function for each member, but perhaps create a single function where you keep the `qsort` calls:

```
void sort_structs(struct XYZ *structs[], size_t count, size_t member_offset)
{//Pass POINTER to array
    switch (member_offset)
    {
        case 0://same cases as above:
            qsort(
                *structs,
                count,
                sizeof *structs[0],//or **structs
                a_sort_callback
            );
            break;
        case offsetof( struct XYZ, b):
            qsort(
                *structs,
                count,
                sizeof *structs[0],
                b_sort_callback
            );
            break;
        case offsetof( struct XYZ, c):
            qsort(
                *structs,
                count,
                sizeof *structs[0],
                c_sort_callback
            );
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(
                stderr,
                "Either %d is invalid offset, or you haven't implemented a callback"
                member_offset
            );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach looks like something I can make use of. Most probably I will not be making use of inbuild qsort function but use something that we write on our own. So I can avoid using the global variable and somehow calculate the offsets whenever required.

Comment: @labyrinth: there's no _"somehow"_ required when it comes to computing the offsets: the `offsetof` macro is standard, and can be found in `stddef.h`. The first member of a struct will always have an offset of `0`, so perhaps you _could_ make that a member that is set to point to the member by which you want to sort, but that's just a horribly messy way of doing things :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Joachim Pileborg pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357442/dynamically-access-member-variable-of-a-structure#comment35773508_23357442), there is a function called `qsort()` in the C Standard lib. You can use it for exactly your purpose. But then you'd have to know what type of array you have and use an appropriate sort function for them.

If, for any reasons, you have distinct struct types you want to be sorted (that would work if you do it via pointers), each of them should provide a key function for extracting the value you want to be sorted for.

If you do so, you effectively build an OOP framework in C.

But the better way is to have a uniform array and provide just a sort function for each type you want to sort.

Comment: "you'd have to extend your struct by a common field" — that would be an extremely misguided and doomed attempt to introduce OO concept where they don't belong. Don't do that kids!

Comment: @n.m What would *you* do if you want to sort some structure components as a string, others as an int and others again as a double?

Comment: I would use `qsort` or exactly as it was designed to be used, passing it different comparator functions *not* stored in my structures. Why would I want to store them there? I only need one comparator function to sort an array, not one comparator function per element.

Comment: @n.m. You are right - for sorting, the array must be uniform - except you choose the key function approach I pointed out. But this makes only sense if at least the type is the same. I'll edit...